# prefersStatusBarHidden slide animation not working on device

Tags: ios, swift, animation, simulator

I have two view controllers. MainViewController and SecondViewController (this one is embedded in a Navigation Controller).
MainViewController has a UIButton that will modally present SecondViewController, while SecondViewController has a UIButton that will dismiss itself.

Each of them have the following code:

```
var statusBarHidden = false {
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { () -> Void in
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    statusBarHidden = true
}
```

The slide animation of the status bar works great in the simulator but not on the actual device, what am i doing wrong ?

I'm using xCode 8.2.1 and Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing was this. I created a variable that links to the view of the status bar and added functions so i can do what i need.

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

    func changeStatusBar(alpha: CGFloat) {
        statusBarView?.alpha = alpha
    }

    func hideStatusBar() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.statusBarView?.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    func showStatusBar() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.statusBarView?.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

A typical use would be:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let alpha = tableView.contentOffset.y / 100
    UIApplication.shared.changeStatusBar(alpha: alpha)

}
```